# How to deploy war (Web Application) to WSO2 EI 6.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Does anyone know how to deploy war (Web Application) to WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.0?
I had a special link in a menu at the previous version WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0, but it is dissapear in the current version.
Below you can find and compare screenshots from both versions:

[WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YusvF.png)

[WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eydQO.png)

Kind Regards,
Kirill Levitskiy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked WSO2 developers about this possibility.
They took desicion - Tomcat should be as separate instance, that's why it was removed from WSO2 EI 6.1.0 package.

Comment: Can you write reason of it? I dont understand why remove this  
comfortable function. And I don't see in mail list answer for this question.

Comment: Hi Ivan,
I've asked WSO2 developers about this at the last meeting.
More details regarding this change you can find at webcast from 62:50 (minutes:seconds): http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2017/05/introducing-the-wso2-enterprise-integrator-6.1/